# how to update HTML image without reloading the page FLASK

Tags: html, forms, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I want to update the user image if he changed the image without reloading the page in flask WTForms

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to change the elements of the page, this can be done with javascript or jquery.

If you want to serve new data without reloading, something like ajax would probably be best.

If you had a data list and were on the home page (/), you could have this in your html:

```
<div id="place_for_data"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$("#search_form_input").keyup(function(){
    var text = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
      url: "/data",
      type: "get",
      data: {jsdata: text},
      success: function(response) {
        $("#place_for_data").html(response);
      },
      error: function(xhr) {
        //Do Something to handle error
      }
    });
});
</script>
```

Then in your `data.html` file:

```
<label id="value_lable">
{% for d in data %}
    {{ d }}<br>
{% endfor %}
</label>
```

With something like this in your flask views:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/data')
def data():
    text = request.args.get('jsdata')

    data = ['data', 'to', 'be', 'returned']
    time.sleep(10)
    return render_template('data.html', data=data)
```